# Error in .bash_profile

Tags: linux, bash, .bash-profile

I am using CentOS 6.2. This is my `~/.bash_profile` content:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

However, when I source it using

```
source .bash_profile
```

it returns

```
if: Expression Syntax.
```

Why?

This is my .bashrc file:

```
# .bashrc
# Source global definitions

if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then

        . /etc/bashrc

fi

# User specific aliases and functions
```

Comment: How does your `~/.bashrc` look? Since it is sourced in `.bash_profile`, the error might be in there (and probably is).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you accidentally ran this from `csh`?

```
$ csh
lucid32:~> source if_rc
if: Expression Syntax.
lucid32:~> cat if_rc
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    :
fi
```

Comment: i changed shell to bash now it's working fine. thanx

Comment: How I did this: _I had a hunch_, having once used tcsh in the grey past.  `if: Expression Syntax.` just did not look like anything that I know from any Bourne/POSIX shell or derivative. Google and a couple of lines of code did the rest.